# Show that it is an element of $L$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $L$ the subfield of the complex  with $\mathbb{Q}\leq L$ a normal extension. If $a=\sqrt{5}-\sqrt[3]{2}\in L$, show that $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}\in L$.

I have done the following:

$Irr(\sqrt{5},\mathbb{Q})=x^2-5$ the roots are $\pm \sqrt{5}\in L$

We have that $a\in L, \sqrt{5}\in L$, $L$ is a field. So $a-\sqrt{5}\in L\Rightarrow \sqrt[3]{2}\in L$

$Irr(\sqrt[3]{2},\mathbb{Q})=x^3-2$ the roots are $\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega\sqrt[3]{2} , \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2}\in L$

We have that $\sqrt[3]{2}\in L, \omega \sqrt[3]{2}\in L$, $L$ is a field. So $\omega \in L$.

Is this correct??

Comment: If $x+y \in L$, you can't deduce that $x,y \in L$. So you can't assume that $\sqrt 5 \in L$

Comment: @user26857 I thought that it stands because the extension is normal and that means that $L$ is the splitting field of a family of polynomials of $\mathbb{Q}$... Is this wrong??

Comment: @Mathmo123 at which point do you mean??

Comment: Yes it's wrong, the extension is normal if $L$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial !

Comment: @MaryStar You have that $a \in L$, but this does not mean that $\sqrt 5, \sqrt[3]2 \in L$.

Comment: I thought that $\sqrt{5}$ is in L because L is the splitting field as  the extension is normal.. And from it follows that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is in L @Mathmo123

Comment: What do you mean by the conjugates of a?? @user26857

Comment: @MaryStar normality tells you that if $x \in L$, then all its conjugates are in $L$. The conjugates of $a$ therefore lie in $L$ - these are the other roots of the minimal polynomial for $a$ over $\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 1):

Once you've shown that $\sqrt5, \sqrt[3]2 \in L$, your proof is correct. To show this fact, you need to show that $$\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5,\sqrt[3]2)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5+\sqrt[3]2)$$and therefore that $a \in L \implies \sqrt5, \sqrt[3]2\in L$. Note that this is not immediate!

Can you show that both these extensions have degree $6$ over $\mathbb Q$? Can you then deduce that they are the same?

Comment: I just add a complement, since $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5,\sqrt[3]2)\supset \mathbb Q(\sqrt 5-\sqrt[3]2)$ and the fact that $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5,\sqrt[3]2):\mathbb Q]=6$ is almost obvious, it just suffice to show that $$[\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5,\sqrt[3]2):\mathbb Q]\notin\{1,2,3\}.$$ which is not that complicated.